# What would cause a thread blocked on a socket send or receive to throw an exception?

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

I'm wondering if anyone knows of perhaps a good article or blog post about what sort of exceptions could be thrown when a program is blocking on a socket send/receive, and more importantly, details of when they would or would not be thrown. MSDN is only so helpful in this instance, and it would be much more educational for me to find an article than for me to try to invoke all of these errors to learn about them myself. Some examples of what I mean:

ThreadInterruptedException - Will throw this exception only when blocking. So if you're reading from a socket, I'm fairly certain it will read the entirety of a buffer before it then tries to block and throws this exception. This is a manually called exception, using thread.interrupt; I've only used this to deal with misbehaving sockets, or closing a blocking, read-only thread to avoid needing to have it poll.

SocketException - Generally what is thrown. This exception can be thrown if the socket is closed while another thread is in the middle of reading/writing. Will this exception be thrown if the network connection is lost while a thread is blocked, waiting for a new receive?

I'm curious about the finer details of what can go wrong because I have a pseudo asynchronous socket library which has a fair number of reads and writes, with a fair amount of code to handle reconnecting and that sort of thing. I'd like to know everything that could possibly go wrong with any of the blocked threads.

Comment: In the threading family of exceptions, the other one is `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Quite true, though I sort of don't count that here, just because I follow the general advice and have no instances of calling Thread.Abort